# Can I put a THREE.js material on a gltf model?

Tags: three.js, 3d, aframe, gltf

Im currently working on my portfolio in A-frame. I'm trying to change the material of the objects to a wireframe material, i'm using the wireframe material (MeshBasicMaterial) of THREE.js to do that. If I put this material on objects like "a-box" or "a-sphere" it works, but i need to put this wireframe material on my 3D gltf model. Is this possible?

This is my script to call the material:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('wireframe', {
             dependencies: ['material'],
             init: function () {
             this.el.components.material.material.wireframe = true;
                }
            });
```

```
<a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" material="color: blue" wireframe></a-box>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to modify the material on a gltf.
One way to do it is to drill into the THREEjs level of the mesh inside the gltf, and create a new material and assign it a wireframe property.

```js
 AFRAME.registerComponent('tree-manager', {         
          init: function () {
            let el = this.el;
            let comp = this;
            let data = this.data;
            comp.scene = el.sceneEl.object3D;  
            comp.counter = 0;   
            comp.treeModels = [];
            comp.modelLoaded = false;

            // After gltf model has loaded, modify it materials.
            el.addEventListener('model-loaded', function(ev){
              let mesh = el.getObject3D('mesh'); 
              if (!mesh){return;}
              //console.log(mesh);
              mesh.traverse(function(node){
                 if (node.isMesh){  
                   let mat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial;
                   let color = new THREE.Color(0xaa5511);
                   mat.color = color;
                   mat.wireframe = true;
                   node.material = mat;                  
                 }
              });
              comp.modelLoaded = true;
            });   
          }
        });

<a-entity id="tree" gltf-model="#tree-gltf" scale="5 5 5"  tree-manager></a-entity>
```

[Here is a glitch](https://glitch.com/%7Egltf-threejsmaterial) that shows how.

Comment: You literally saved my life Thomas! Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped. Now you know how to access THREEjs properties in Aframe. This is VERY powerful.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams Belated welcome to Stack Overflow!  The community here would appreciate very much if you could copy the actual lines of code for the solution into your answer here (via editing the answer).  Stack Overflow likes to have a local copy of the answer, in case external links expire or change unexpectedly.  Thanks so much!